# Unable to install Multi-variate packages in python

Tags: python, pip, package, installation

I am trying to import the packages:

```
 from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
 from statsmodels.base.model import Model
```

However, I get an error saying:

ImportError: No module named multivariate_ols

when, I try installing using pip using following command:

```
 python -m pip install multivariate_ols
```

I get following errors:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement multivariate_ols (from versions: )   
No matching distribution found for multivariate_ols
```

My python version is:  Python 2.7.15rc1

Can any help me get rid of this?

Comment: `pip install -U statsmodels` - [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/install.html). If you're on `windows`, make sure you install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

Comment: The command didn't work. And I am on the Linux environment

Comment: In what way it failed?